# Syntax for a Unicode constant in Apex?

Tags: apex, string

Let's say you wanted to create a String constant of a Unicode non-breaking whitespace. This is Unicode `U+00A0`

```
String nbsp = ????;
```

The SFDC doc is maddeningly incomplete on this topic. [The section on Primitives](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm) doesn't say anything relevant and if your thoughts turned to escape sequences, what is listed doesn't address Unicode:

> Escape Sequences: All Strings in Apex use the same escape sequences as SOQL strings: \b (backspace), \t (tab), \n (line feed), \f (form feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double quote), \' (single quote), and \ (backslash).

Does one escape Unicode sequences? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SFDC doc tells you the answer in "indirect" places:

String class [charAt method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

```
String str = '\uD835\uDD0A';
System.assertEquals(55349, str.charAt(0), 
    'charAt(0) didn\'t return the high surrogate.');
System.assertEquals(120074, str.codePointAt(0),
    'codePointAt(0) didn\'t return the entire two-character supplementary value.');
```

also String class method `codePointAtIndex`

```
String str = '\u03A9 is Ω (Omega), and \uD835\uDD0A ' + 
    ' is Fraktur Capital G.';
System.assertEquals(937, str.codePointAt(0));
System.assertEquals(120074, str.codePointAt(20));
// Escaped or unescaped forms of the same character have the same code point
System.assertEquals(str.codePointAt(0), str.codePointAt(5));
```

So,

```
String nbsp = '\u00A0';
```

Looking at [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) (what Apex is based on), Unicode characters are not technically considered escape sequences, even though they start with `\`;

Instead, consider  `'\uxxxx'` as a character (Unicode) literal and as legitimate as `'a'` or `'日'`